# Why is user data not storing into firebase firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I have functions that Sign up users but i can't seemed why it is not storing the users information in firebase firestore.

My Sign Up user functions:

```js
//Signing up the user
export function* signUpUser({ payload: {  displayName, surname, email, password, cellphone, address, province, tcCheckbox} }) {
    
    try {

        const user = yield auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        const additionalData = { displayName, surname, cellphone, address, province, tcCheckbox};
        yield getSnapshotFromUserAuth(user, additionalData);
  
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

From my Sign up user function I get `'getSnapshotFromUserAuth'`

```js
export function* getSnapshotFromUserAuth(user, additionalData = {}) {
    try {
        
          const userRef = yield call(handleUserProfile, { userAuth: user, additionalData });
          const snapshot = yield userRef.get();
          
          
          yield put(signInSuccess({
            id: snapshot.id,
            ...snapshot.data()
          }))
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
};
```

Which calls handleUserProfile in my firebase `utils.js`

```js
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export const handleUserProfile = async ({ userAuth, additionalData }) => {
if (!userAuth) return;
const { uid } = userAuth;
  
const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`);
const snapshot = await userRef.get();
  
if (!snapshot.exists) {
  const { displayName, surname, email } = userAuth;
  const timestamp = new Date();
  const userRoles = ['user'];
  
  try {
    await userRef.set({
      displayName,
      email,
      surname,
      createdDate: timestamp,
      userRoles,
      ...additionalData
    });
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
  
return userRef;
};
```

The code is signing up the user but not storing all the additional data that i want to store with the user

Comment: Make sure you are not saving `undefined` value on any field

Comment: None of my fields are undefined when i `console.log` all the objects out, but after the users signs in I get this error now `FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field surname in document user/jFCQmnEQkTfYk7lk8IJyenCrPbq1)` but this is because my getSnapshotFromUserAuth is not getting user uid because its not storing the users data

Answer (score 1):

I would think this is related with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. This method returns object `UserCredential`. Please check the [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword) and [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account).

So in the code there is `user` assignment and I think this should be corrected to:

```
const user = yield auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).user;
```

More or less like in the example. I do not have a playground to test it, so please share the result.

Comment: Thanks, It solves my problem storing the user information to firestore but brought another problem that my user information was coming back `null`for all the additional fields which i solved by passing the userRoles into the 'try/catch ' block.

Answer (score -1):

`const { displayName, email, surname, cellphone, address, province, tcCheckbox } = userAuth;`

did you mean `additionalData` instead of `userAuth`?

Comment: I tried destructuring the data from `additionalData` but  it still throw me an error of `undefined` for the properties I destructed

Comment: okay but it's obviously wrong to destructure the data from ```userAuth``` when your code show clearly shows that the data is in ```additionalData```!

Quote: ```const additionalData = { displayName, surname, cellphone, address, province, tcCheckbox};```

Comment: I also thought at first, but i forgot that I assigned the additional data to the 'userAuth' object so it stores into firebase without storing 2 different objects